# Thread access info plugin for Inteliji Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I have installed the 'Thread Access Info' plugin in IntelliJ IDEA, but it seems not to be working. Ideally, when debugging code, a separate 'Thread Access' tab should appear, showing what's happening with the thread, but it's not showing up for me. I'm coding in Java.

Could you please help me understand why it's not working?

[image]

[image]

Installed the plugin, tried reinstalling, nothing helped

Comment: Did you try contacting the maintainer of that plugin/creating an issue in the corresponding issue tracker?

Comment: Earlier did not write, now sent an email, will wait for a response, but in any case if anyone has encountered such a problem and can explain the reasons why the plugin may not work, would be grateful.